# R - Exceeding a threshold of row repetitions in a given period of time (with a condition)

Tags: r, dplyr, count, rows, lubridate

I would like to know which `ID` is repeated at least a certain amount of times (eg: ≥3) in a given period (2 years).
These are the conditions for the results: I would like to get a `TRUE` result if the `ID` is repeated ≥3 times in a 2-year period if ≥1 of those times is before `index`.
If the `ID` is repeated <3 times or ≥3 times but in a period larger than 2 years, or ≥3 times in 2 years but solely after `index` or ≥3 times before and after `index` but not in a 2-year period, I want the result to be `FALSE`.
I have the following table as an example:

```
ID  Date        index
1   1998-08-04  2002-04-05
1   1999-12-01  2002-04-05
1   1999-12-12  2002-04-05
2   2000-04-04  2001-06-13
2   2001-08-12  2001-06-13
2   2001-10-18  2001-06-13
3   2002-04-04  2002-09-12
3   2002-05-08  2002-09-12
4   2006-04-08  2001-01-03
4   2006-12-18  2001-01-03
4   2007-01-01  2001-01-03
5   2007-07-07  2007-08-12
5   2012-04-03  2007-08-12
5   2012-05-03  2007-08-12
5   2012-06-06  2007-08-12
6   2012-05-04  2021-04-09
6   2012-07-04  2021-04-09
6   2016-04-08  2021-04-09
6   2016-05-22  2021-04-09
6   2020-01-01  2021-04-09
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
ID  Rep
1   TRUE
2   TRUE
3   FALSE
4   FALSE
5   FALSE
6   FALSE
```

I've been doing something like this, to count for repeated `ID` in a 2-year period:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(Rep = sum(diff(Date)<(2*365.25))>=2)
```

I get the following result but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm also not being able to use `index` as a reference for each `ID` group.

```
ID Rep   
1 TRUE 
2 TRUE 
3 FALSE
4 TRUE 
5 TRUE 
6 TRUE
```

Maybe I need to add an `IF` statement or `case_when` but I really don't know how to continue.
Any thoughts?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sharing your dataframe via `dput()` could help test a solution.